# Why bulk loading a Vertica database table does not load all lines?

Tags: vertica

I have a small csv file I would like to bulk load into a Vertica 6.1 database table, this file has 92 lines.

```
dbadmin=> COPY games FROM '/tmp/games.csv' DELIMITER ',';
 Rows Loaded
-------------
          44
```

The file is 92 lines, but Vertica only loads 44 lines. 
As a test, I tried loading the same file in MySQL, and all 92 lines loaded fine.

I verified the file has 92 lines.

```
[root@localhost tmp]# cat /tmp/games.csv | wc -l
92
```

I opened the file and verified it has no unusual characters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try option ABORT ON ERROR - will output a reason for rejection.

```
COPY 'table name' FROM '/path/to/data.txt' DIRECT RECORD TERMINATOR ',' ABORT ON ERROR
```

Check rejected and exception files or define it in COPY:

```
COPY 'table name' FROM '/path/to/data.txt' DIRECT RECORD TERMINATOR ',' REJECTED DATA 'path' EXCEPTIONS 'path'
```

https://community.vertica.com/vertica/topics/bulk_loading

(Original URL is dead; you can try [this one](https://my.vertica.com/get-started-vertica/loading-data-basics/) instead)